# Total count in Google appengine fulltext search

Tags: java, google-app-engine, count, full-text-search

I'm trying to count total rows of a fulltext search document. In  [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview#Queries_on_Fields) appear the expression count(size) however I do not get it to work.

I'm working in Java.

Is there any example about how to use 'count' expression?

Comment: where u able to figured out this? Im looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    public void countRows() {
    GetRequest request = GetRequest.newBuilder().setReturningIdsOnly(true)
            .build();
    int totalResult = (int) INDEX.getRange(request).getResults().size();
}
```

You have to declare :

```
    private Index INDEX = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(
        IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("your_doc_name"));
```

Note that : it's better if you don't count rows. For pagination, it should be next and previuos page link only. Sorry if my English is not good.